# Winform always stays in front of other applications

Tags: c#, winforms, window

I'm having a problem where a winforms application I wrote is always in front of other applications.

Its `TopMost` property is set to `false` and yet whenever I click on anything else on my computer (Google Chrome, Windows Explorer, etc) the winforms application stays in front of them, albeit grayed out. This means that to effectively use other applications while my winforms app is running, I have to minimize it.

I'm wondering if there's a way to change it so that it works like a normal application, where it goes behind other windows that are clicked on without minimizing or closing it

Pics:
Upon opening the app
[image: Upon opening the app]

Upon clicking on VS
[image: Upon clicking on VS]

As you can see, clicking on visual studio does gray out the app, but the app still shows in front of VS. This is the same behavior with all other windows.

Here are the properties of the form:
[image]

And the rest of the properties:
[image]

Comment: Any chance you can show a screenshot of the window properties in the VS Forms Editor?  Particularly those properties shown as **bold**.  This will help us help you.  Good luck!

Comment: Sure thing, gimme a few minutes

Comment: The pictures are up now

Comment: @EliezerMiron: From the look of the form properties there's nothing abnormal. Are you sure the `TopMost' property is not set within code (either within the same form or any parent control)?

Comment: Thanks.  Hmm nothing that leaps out there (pun not intended).  I used your settings and was not able to reproduce sadly.  How do you show your form?  e.g. `Application.Run(new Form1());` ?

Comment: @fujiFX I think you're right, one of the methods might mess with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that one of the methods does programmatically change the value of TopMost to true, so that was causing my problem. Thanks to fujiFX for pointing that out as a possible reason